# How to use azcopy version 10.3.0 to copy and then delete file from Blob storage to VM using powershell

Tags: azcopy

Some csv files keep getting placed in an azure storage container. I need to continuously move the files to a VM. I am using the following powershell script running on my VM.

```
while($true){
.\azcopy sync "source blob" "destination folder on VM" --include-pattern "*.csv" --log-level ERROR
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

The files are getting copied, but how do I delete the files from the source. They are not needed anymore after copying to the VM.

Comment: Hello, if the answer works for you, could you please help mark it as answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I scoured the interwebs for this and still none of the "solutions" were sufficient. 
 *SO* -- I had to write my own.  Below is the code I wrote that will do the following: 

**a. Download AZCopy if it doesnt exist.

b. Copy information from an Azure blob storage

c. Upon successful copy, delete information from source**


https://github.com/SlkRck/demoscripts/blob/master/copy-blobstorage.ps1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [azcopy remove command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-remove?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json) after the `azcopy sync` operation is completed. And here I need to mention that the `azcopy sync` operation is thread-blocking, so it's safe to use `azcopy rm` command at the end of the `azcopy sync` operation.

Note that if you want to just remove all the .csv file, you should add `--include-pattern="*.csv"` in the command.

I'm using the latest version of [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy), v10.3.1. If you prefer to use v10.3.0, then first you need to use this command `azcopy remove --help` for the details of this command and it's parameters.

A sample command like below:

```
while($true){
.\azcopy sync "source blob" "destination folder on VM" --include-pattern "*.csv" --log-level ERROR
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

#after the copy operation is completed, use remove command as below.
azcopy.exe rm "https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/test4?sastoken" --include-pattern="*.csv" --recursive=true

}
```

One thing need to mention, in my test, I use the sas token for my testing purpose.